# Expo Notification and Firebase Cloud messaging

Tags: expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

I am trying to implement Firebase Cloud messaging using expo notification.

When I trigger a notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging Console the notification gets through but when

I try to use the expo-server-sdk-python. It throws an error

`ExponentPushToken[Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]" is not a registered notification recipient`

As mentioned in Expo Docs when using Expo's notification service we generate the ExponentPushToken using

`const token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data`

I don't know what's going wrong here the notification triggered from FCM dashboard gets through but when using the server side API it doesn't work